# Gson lib parsing error Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

Getting below error for the Gson parsing for below JSON

11-05 15:34:00.882: W/System.err(28673): com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 5923

```
 {
  "lab": [
    [
      {
        "id": "147",
        "messagelab_id": "test",
        "patientlab_ic": "abc",
        "patientlab_name": "some text"

      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

i have used below model classes for above JSON

```
public class ScreeningResults implements Serializable{

    private Labs lab;
    //@SerializedName("all_results")
    //private List<LabResult> labResults;

    public Labs getLab() {
        return lab;
    }
    public void setLab(Labs lab) {
        this.lab = lab;
    }


}


public class Labs implements Serializable{

 private List<Lab> lab;

public List<Lab> getLab() {
    return lab;
}

public void setLab(List<Lab> lab) {
    this.lab = lab;
}


}
```

i am using belo lines to parse serialize above JSON

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
  ScreeningResults screeningResults=gson.fromJson(response.toString(),ScreeningResults.class);
```

Comment: your json is invalid,replace **"some text",** to **"some text"**

Comment: Edited assume JSON is valid

Comment: As your json sturcture is like this "lab": [
    [
     so it must be List<List<Lab>>

Comment: Instead of lists, it should also be happy with `Lab[][]`. When you say `Labs lab` if looks for `"lab" : { /* content defined in Labs class */ }`, i.e. an object

Comment: @zap1 I have chnaged to 
   private List<List<Lab>> lab; not its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON contains a two-dimensional array. So instead of `List<Lab>` you should parse it to `List<List<Lab>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working Domain class for above JSON

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ScreeningResults implements Serializable{

//private Labs lab;
private List<List<Lab>> lab;


public List<List<Lab>> getLab() {
    return lab;
}

public void setLab(List<List<Lab>> lab) {
    this.lab = lab;
}
```